# Updating WPF window labels while loading a new window

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker, splash-screen

I have tried everything including the Background Worker and Dispatcher and I cannot figure out how to do this.

Here is what I am trying to accomplish.

My WPF 'MainWindow' has a series of functions it completes before it renders. It takes a total of 20 seconds to complete. Because of this, I have created a window called 'LoadWindow'. I have the 'LoadWindow' ContentRendered event set to load my 'MainWindow' and then close itself upon completion. I basically have created a SplashScreen.

```
 private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
     mainWindow.Show();
     this.Close();
 }
```

I would like one of my labels, let's call it 'splashLabel' to update as each function is fired in my 'MainWindow' code behind. these functions are called during my grids layoutRoot Initialize event. As I currently have it my splashLabel will not render even the though content has been changed.

```
 private void layOutRoot_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     LoadWindow.splashLabel.content = "Function 1";
     Function1();
     LoadWindow.splashLabel.content = "Function 2";
     Function2();
     LoadWindow.splashLabel.content = "Function 3";
     Function3();
 }
```

Please point me in the right direction! My days of googling have not helped.

Comment: I'm a little confused about the question. You are trying to show the user that the application is loading? If that is the case it might be easier just to have a loading spinner in your window and show it until it has finished loading. With this approach you would not need another window

Comment: @ShawnKendrot Yes that would be easier, but the end goal here is to have a splash screen comparable to Microsoft Office. When Office loads, there is an animated label that tells you what is being loaded (Add-ins and such). I would like my users to see what is being done, before showing the window.

Comment: What's the issue? You've told us what you want to happen, but haven't yet told us what's *actually* happening.

Comment: @Jashaszun That is just it. Nothing is happening. Sorry I wasn't clear. My label doesn't want to render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a step back, you've got a slow loading window which you want to report progress on?

If so, what I have found to work well in the past is to add an overlay to your control which hides all your content and has a label on it to report status. Bind the visibility of that to an IsBusy property. Bind your label to a Status property.

Then in your view model, assuming MVVM, define your functions as async. Then write a simple function which calls these in turn and updates the properties mentioned. Something like...

```
Private async void DoLoadingTasks()
{
     IsBusy = true;
     await Function1();
     Status = "step complete";
     ....
     IsBusy = false;
}
```

Call that method from your view model constructor and you should have a responsive UI and notifications of progress.

Does that do what you want?

Comment: That seems like a perfect solution, however I don't think you can really use async in VS2010? Correct me if I am wrong but wasn't that implemented in VS2012. I sadly have not upgraded.

Comment: It is part of .Net 4 and was available as a preview, but I wouldn't want that in my production code.

Comment: You can still do the same with background workers. I always used to start a background worker with a start method. So create your BWs and create StartBW1 etc as helper methods to launch them. I find this useful as a place to add a test on if the worker is already running. In that helper, increment a counter in your view model called runningThreads and set IsBusy to runningThreads > 0. Do the same in your completed event handler but decrement the counter. That way, your UI should show your busy overlay whenever a BW is running. Replace the above method with calls to all the starter helpers.

Comment: It feels kind of messy. But hey if it works it works and it does work. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Yes - async does get rid of a lot of the boilerplate code you put in for backgroundworker. Glad it worked for you.